# Pattern match element of list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
def contains(x: Int, l: List[Int]) = l match { // this is just l.contains(x)
  case _ :: x :: _ => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work

```
scala> contains(0, List(1, 2, 3))
res21: Boolean = true

scala> contains(1, List(1, 2, 3))
res22: Boolean = true

scala> contains(3, List(1, 2, 3))
res23: Boolean = true
```

Could you please explain why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a number equal to `x` you can put it into backticks:

```
def contains(x: Int, l: List[Int]) = l match {
  case _ :: `x` :: _ => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Unfortunately `::` matcher takes exactly one item from list – the first one, so this code would work only to find the second item in `l`:

```
scala> contains(1, List(1,2,3))
res2: Boolean = false

scala> contains(2, List(1,2,3))
res3: Boolean = true

scala> contains(3, List(1,2,3))
res4: Boolean = false
```

I believe, you can't match for an arbitrary item in a list without recursion:

```
def contains(x: Int, l: List[Int]): Boolean = l match { // this is just l.contains(x)
  case `x` :: xs => true
  case _ :: xs => contains(x, xs)
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about _backticks_. It is a pity that `::` takes exactly one item :(

Answer (score 1):

The first case matches any item in a non empty list, note,

```
scala> contains(123, List(1, 2, 3))
res1: Boolean = true

scala> contains(123, List())
res2: Boolean = false
```

A recursive method that matches against the head item of the list may work.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I do not want recursion.

Answer (score 1):

First, `x` in `case` section is alias for local variable. It's not `x` you passed to method.

Second, `_ :: x :: _` matches any list with two elements and more. So all your outputs is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work,

```
  def contains(y: Int, l: List[Int]) = l match { // this is just l.contains(x)
    case _ :: x :: _  if(x == y)=> true
    case _ => false
  }
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Can I get rid of this `if(x == y)` somehow ?

Comment: @Michael, Why you don't want that guard condition?

Comment: Just for aesthetic reasons

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not work, because the `x` in the pattern match is bound to whatever value the second list element has. It's basically a fresh variable.

Alternative to S.K's answer

```
def contains(y: Int, l: List[Int]) = l match { // this is just l.contains(x)
  case _ :: x :: _  => x == y
  case _ => false
}
```

or you can also write

```
def contains[A](y: A, l: Seq[Int]) = (l.lift)(1).exists(_ == y)
```